# How to modify the MDN Decimal Rounding example to ALWAYS (even when they are all zeroes) display decimal places for monetary representation

Tags: javascript

I found this [MDN Decimal Rounding example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) really neat. It does almost exactly what I want it to do. Almost, because when I do:

```
Math.round10((6.9544 + 6.95001), -2);
```

The output is displayed as 13.9, rather than the desired 13.90, as this is for monetary representation.
Your time's greatly appreciated.
Jared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.toFixed(2)`

Like this:

```
(6.9544 + 6.95001).toFixed(2); // "13.90"
```

`.toFixed(2)` rounds of to two places and returns a string.

`.toFixed` rounds it for you already but if you really want to go with `Math.round10`, you can do this:

```
Math.round10((6.9544 + 6.95001), -2).toFixed(2)
```

Both `Math.round10` and `toFixed` does the same thing.

Comment: You probably mean `Math.round10((6.9544 + 6.95001), -2).toFixed(2)` because otherwise it's not correct.

Comment: @ArtjomB.,no I meant what I meant. That won't give the result which my answer gives

Comment: For this example they will be the same, but for 6.9544 + 6.95401 they will be different.

Comment: Amit +1, as your answer does the trick, but doesn't do the rounding I'm after, as Artjom pointed out, the input values can be arbitrary and correct rounding counts, thus I agree with @Artjom - If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you all.

Comment: @JaredTomaszewski, toFixed rounds it for you. So why do you want it?

Comment: @JaredTomaszewski, you don't need `Math.round10` as `.toFixed` automatically does it for you.

Comment: Thank you Amit, you are right. You earned your reward back :)
@ArtjomB. Sorry mate, life's a beach ;)

Comment: glad to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Math.round10((6.9544 + 6.95001), -2).toFixed(2)
```

for when your number should be rounded and not only cut off (see answer from [Amit Joki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23518046/1816580)).